# onclick funtion when I add a button in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to use AJAX to get information. If succeeds, I want to append the data into a table. Also, in each `tr`, I add a button, and I want to trigger an event if I click the button. Thus, I just append a button with an `onclick` function into the table. While, the `onclick` function does not work. Does anyone know why? and how I can reach my goal?

Here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+tag+'/media/recent',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    data:{
        access_token: access_token,
        count: count
    },
    success: function(data){
       for(var x in data.data){
         var html="";
         tdHtml +="<tr><td>"+"<a href='"+data.data[x].link+"'><img src='"+data.data[x].images.thumbnail.url+"'></img></a>"+"</td>"+ 
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+data.data[x].caption.from.username+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+data.data[x].likes.count+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+create_time+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+tags+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+"<button id='addUsers' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onclick='addUsers()'>Add Users to a Group</button>"+"</td></tr>";
     }
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**
Actually, the `onclick` function is like this:

```
 "<td>"+"<button id='addUsers' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onclick='addUsers('"+data.data[x].caption.from.username+"')'>Add Users to a Group</button>"+"</td></tr>";)'>Add Users to a Group</button>"+"</td></tr>";
```

Once I click the button, I can do something with the data's username I get via AJAX. However, even if I write simply, it cannot work. For example:

```
function addUsers(name){
  console.log(name);
}
```

The name cannot be consoled. There is an undefined error, or other error happened.

So, the goal for me is to get response from developer(done), append it to a table in html(done), and click a button(which was append formerly) to do more things with the appended information. Here, I want to add the name into a certain list.

Comment: I do not see where `tdHtml` is used. Let's suppose it is used :) What is the error in console?

Comment: my guess is you didn't use event delegation dynamically created buttons.

Comment: add the code from `addUsers()`

Comment: Also, note that you create buttons with **non-unique** ids. `id` should always be **unique**.

Comment: your initialized variable name is html but your using here is tdHtml  but this is ok we can use ,can you provide your code here ..then i can test where you r getting what is the error and what's going here...

Comment: @roshini Here is a new version! Thanks!

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Even I delete the id it still not work.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Maybe the problem is about the para in the function addUsers()

Comment: @guradio Here it is! Thanks!

Comment: The error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: in what scope is function `addUsers` defined?

Comment: @Igor It was just written in js file.

Comment: also, if I change to onclick='"addUsers(data.data[x].caption.from.username)"', the error is Uncaught ReferenceError: p is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up your quotes:

```
"<td>"+"<button id='addUsers' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' " +
  "onclick='addUsers(\""+
  data.data[x].caption.from.username+
  "\")'>Add Users to a Group</button>"+
  "</td></tr>";
```

Note `\"` wrapping the parameter for `addUsers`.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the key problem. Do you have any idea about how can I revise it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the button is causing a postback and hence reloading the page again
try to use this instead of button

```html
<input type='button' id='addUsers' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onclick='addUsers()' value='Add Users to a Group' />
```

Comment: The button can work, while the function cannot get the right username string. Maybe matter's about quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe another way to do this and avoid duplicated event attributes:

1. Invent a class. For instance, let's call it simply `addUsersButton`.
2. Add this class to your button while dynamically creating it:

   ```
   tdHtml += /* ... other code here */ +
       "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs addUsersButton'>Add Users to a Group</button>";
   ```

   Note that there is no `onclick` attribute.
3. Now, using **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**, define the following handler:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', 'addUsersButton', function() {
       var username = $(this).parent().find('td:eq(1)').text();
       addUsers(username);
   });
   ```

   Now, all of your `addUsersButtons` will trigger this event whether they are dynamically generated or not.

   `$(this).parent().find('td:eq(1)').text()` will work because you store `data.data[x].caption.from.username` in the second cell of the current row. However, it is not a best idea to use this approach. You can declare some kind of `data-username` attribute and access it using `$(selector).data('username')`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use event delegation, and here is the sample:

html:

```
<button id="addContentBtn"> add content to table</button>
<table id="testTbl"></table>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   ("#addContentBtn").click(function(){
        var str="<tr><td>1</td><td><button>button</button></td></tr>" +
         "<tr><td>2</td><td><button>button</button></td></tr>" ;
        $(str).appendTo("#testTbl");
   })

   //this is event delegation
   $("#testTbl").on("click","button",function(){
                alert("clicked");
   })
```

});